# Power Off and Capacitor Discharge

Tags: diodes, protection, debounce

Could someone tell me where this diode (highlighted part) would be added and the orientation?

https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/287

[image]

Comment: This sounds like a design question, which is really up to you to decide on how you want to do this. Why doesn't _Figure 3_ satisfy what you need?

Comment: The circuit as shown in the app note simply does not work. There is NO input signal to the Schmitt trigger. I can't believe they don't have an errata sheet for the app note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sense the circuit should have a connection from the top of the capacitor to the input of the Schmitt trigger. To protect the input on power-down from the charge held in the cap you need a diode that connects from the input to Vcc. But you already have a diode there, its the top one of the 2 in series.

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to add an excerpt from a datasheet I ran across for a MC14490 Hex Contact Bounce Eliminator.  The datasheet discussed power down considerations for the IC which seemed to apply to this topic.

[image]